# Bourne Legacy and Paranoia?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-bourne-legacy

I know *The Bourne Legacy* is an old movie but I just watched it.  I actually really liked it.  The performances are great, the story is a little convoluted but that's par for the course in the Bourne universe, and probably one of the best car/bike chase scenes in a movie in a very long time.

Something bothered me though after looking up a bit of information about the movie.  I never really understood a couple of Aaron Cross's actions in the movie and I found something that said there are deleted scenes that indicate all the OUTCOME agents were having severe paranoia and that influenced a lot of his actions in the movie.

Okay, great.  However that made something else bother me even more.  We see at least 3 different OUTCOME agents murdered by switching their blue/green pills out for a yellow pill.  Huh?  If all these agents are suffering from severe paranoia how do they take a new pill without so much as a raised eyebrow?

Comment: Whoa, did you just call 2012's *Bourne Legacy* an *"old movie"*? ;-)

Comment: From the point of view that I didn't expect anyone else to be discussing it still.

Comment: Well, we're also discussing movies that are 90 years old afterall.

Comment: I just found this.  Still poking around.

Comment: Sure, welcome to the site and take you time with it, it's a great place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think those scenes were deleted so that the idea of them switching out the pills wouldn't be as far fetched.  Without those deleted scenes, those actions of Cross that you found confusing could have been related to Cross alone having moments of paranoia, or possibly being overly-careful about certain situations.

Sometimes movies evolve, and certain scenes are cut because they no longer make sense.  Now, if those cut scenes are ever inserted into a Director's Cut or something, then I'd say it was a plot hole.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that the agents were paranoid, it's that they were all trying to lengthen their leashes, so to speak.  Some were found to have created identities that NRAG didn't know about (like Aaron had), and some had managed to stockpile extra medications (like Aaron was trying to do with his mountain shortcut stunt).  Ultimately, they were all looking for a way to escape the program while retaining their enhancements.  They were superintelligent slaves, after all.

The yellow pills would have seemed like a positive development to them, since those only needed to be taken every eight days instead of every day.  And with their own schemes in mind, it never occurred to them that NRAG had decided to up and kill them.  So the deleted scene didn't undermine anything, it was just cut for pacing.  Anyway, the scene where Oscar Isaac's character starts to thaw out to Aaron ("Don't worry about the chems, I've got that covered.") did the same work.